# KendoUI Mobile Zoomable Scrollview

Tags: javascript, user-interface, kendo-ui, zooming, scrollview

I am currently working on a project where I need to use the Scrollview widget to display images. What I am unable to do is to enable "zooming" of an image using "pinch to zoom" within the scrollview, I am only able to do that in a separate view.

How can I add the zooming feature into a Scrollview, as in the native gallery / photo viewers on mobile devices?